# Не експортируется CarouselCaption с reactstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, reactjs

Привет!Я решил установить reactstrap(Bootstrap для react)чтобы использовать систему сеток и устоновить слайдер на сайт но при установке слайдера я получаю вот такую ошибку

```
./src/Components/Slider.js
103:30-45 'reactstrap' does not contain an export named 'CarouselCaption'.
```

вот мой код

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselControl,
  CarouselIndicators,
  CarouselCaption
} from 'reactstrap';

const items = [
    {
      src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa1d%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa1d%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.921875%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
      altText: 'Slide 1',
      caption: 'Slide 1'
    },
    {
      src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa20%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa20%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
      altText: 'Slide 2',
      caption: 'Slide 2'
    },
    {
      src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa21%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa21%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
      altText: 'Slide 3',
      caption: 'Slide 3'
    }
  ];

  class Slider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { activeIndex: 0 };
      this.next = this.next.bind(this);
      this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
      this.goToIndex = this.goToIndex.bind(this);
      this.onExiting = this.onExiting.bind(this);
      this.onExited = this.onExited.bind(this);
    }

    onExiting() {
      this.animating = true;
    }

    onExited() {
      this.animating = false;
    }

    next() {
      if (this.animating) return;
      const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === items.length - 1 ? 0 : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
      this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
    }

    previous() {
      if (this.animating) return;
      const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? items.length - 1 : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
      this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
    }

    goToIndex(newIndex) {
      if (this.animating) return;
      this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });
    }

    render() {
      const { activeIndex } = this.state;

      const slides = items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <CarouselItem
            onExiting={this.onExiting}
            onExited={this.onExited}
            key={item.src}
          >
            <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
            <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />
          </CarouselItem>
        );
      });

      return (
        <Carousel
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          next={this.next}
          previous={this.previous}
        >
          <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
          {slides}
          <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
          <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
        </Carousel>
      );
    }
  }


  export default Slider;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import FaAlignJustify from 'react-icons/lib/fa/align-justify';
import FaShoppingCart from 'react-icons/lib/fa/shopping-cart';
import FaSearch from 'react-icons/lib/fa/search';
import Slider from "./Slider";


class Header extends Component {
     render() {
         return(
         <div>
             <div className="HeaderMain">
             <div className="DropMenu" >
             <ul className ="MenuButtons" id="TopNav" >
                     <li className="MenuHeader"><FaAlignJustify /></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><img src="/images/portland.jpg" alt="portlandlogo"/></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Delivery & Payment</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><div className="CartMain">
                < FaShoppingCart /><span>Cart</span>
                <div className="Cart-container"><span className="Cart-span"></span><span className="Cart-text">0</span></div></div></li>
                <li className="Visible"><button className="HeaderBtn">Sign in</button></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="SecondMenuMain">
                <ul className="SecondMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">TOP SALES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BRAND FOCUS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HI-TECH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BEST SELLERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" className="Support">SUPPORT</a></li>
                    <li className="Bordered"><div><FaSearch className="Search" /><input placeholder="I`m looking for..."></input></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>   
                <Slider />>
            </div>
         </div>);


    }
}

export default Header;
```

Подскажите почему я получаю такую ошибку и как ее исправить?

Comment: Какую версию `reactstrap` вы используете? Так же у вас проблемы с разметкой в компоненте `Header`.

Comment: Делал как тут написано
https://reactstrap.github.io/
"reactstrap": "^4.8.0"

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте попробовал бы пофиксить проблемы с разметкой, хотя думаю  что это дело не в этом. 
Посмотрите в `node_modules` на моудуль `reactstrap` и проверьте есть ли у вас в этом модуле `CarouselCaption`. Если нету, попробуйте переустановить или попробуйте его создать вручную, вот он сам. https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/CarouselCaption.js

Comment: Переустановил и все заработало)